# Is $\frac{5\pi}{6}$ a transcendental or an algebraic number?

Tags: proof-writing, algebraic-number-theory, pi, transcendental-numbers, golden-ratio

$\Phi^2$ is an algebraic number as it is the root of $x^2-3x+1=0$

So knowing that $\frac{\pi}{6} = \frac{\Phi^2}{5}$, which is a relation I saw, does it mean that $\frac{5\pi}{6}$ is algebraic despite $\pi$ being transcendental?

How would you prove that it is or it is not?

Comment: `which is a known relation I saw` Where? The equality surely doesn't hold, though the two numbers *are* in fact close [$5 \pi / 6 - \phi^2\simeq -0.00004011 \ldots$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=5+pi+%2F+6+-+goldenRatio%5E2)

Comment: Where did you see that identity?

Comment: If $5\pi\over 6$ is algebraic, then so is $\pi$.  It sounds like the "known relation" is highly suspect...

Comment: $phi^2- 5\pi/6 = 0.00004011...$

Comment: That's definitely *not* an algebraic number.

Comment: It would.  If $\Phi^2 = \frac {5\pi}6$.  But $\frac 56*\pi$ is clearly not algebraic.  So $\frac {5\pi}6 = \Phi^2$ is clearly not a root to $x^2 -3x + 1 = 0$.

Comment: So a transcendental number can never be algebraic no matter its coefficient?

Comment: "So a transcendental number can never be algebraic no matter its coefficient?"  Obviously. If $P(x)$ is a polynomial with rational coefficients then $P(q x)=Q(x)$ is a polynomial with rational coefficients.  Of $P(qx) = 0$ then $Q(x) =0$ and $x$ is algebraic.

Comment: Okay, a coefficient of $0$ or a non-rational transcendtal coefficennt can yield an algebraic number.  $0*\pi=0$ and $(\frac 2{\pi}* \pi)=2$ are algebraic.

Comment: Can you explain this part $P(q x)=Q(x)$ and what does letter case q stand for?

Comment: Let $t$ be transcendental. Suppose $q*t$ is not trascendental for a rational $q$. Let $P(x) = \sum_{i=0}^n a_ix^i$ be a polynomial with rational coefficients so that $P(q*t) = 0$.  Then let $Q(x) = \sum_{i=0}^n (q^i*a_i)x^i$ is a polynomial with rationall coefficients.  And $Q(t) = \sum_{i=0}^n (q^i*a_i)t^i= P(q*t) =0$.  But this contradicts that $t$ is transcendental. So $q*t$ must be transcendental too.

Answer (score 3):

Very easily.  If $\frac56 \pi=a$, where $a$ is algebraic, then $\pi=\frac65 a$...  This implies $\pi$  is algebraic...

Note:  the product of algebraic numbers is algebraic...

Comment: Can any product of $\pi$ be algebraic?

Comment: @MartinGwynn Any algebraic number times $\pi$ is transcendental.

Comment: $0*\pi$ and $x*\pi$ where $x$ is transcendental, can be algebraic.  But $a*\pi$ where $a$ is algebraic and $a\ne 0$ can not be.  No.  Absolutely not.  Never. No way, no how.

Comment: @WeijunZhou except $0$.  $0*\pi$ is algebraic.

Comment: @fleablood Yes, forget that bit. And +1 for never, no way, no how.

Comment: $a$ is Algebraic means there exists a polynomial with rational coefficients (of at least degree 1) $P$ so that $P(a)=0$.  If $q \ne 0$ is rational, then $P(q x) = Q(x)$ is a polynomial with rational coefficients with at least degree 1.   If $q*x$ is such that $P(q*x) = 0$ then $ Q(x) = 0$ so $x$ must be algebraic.  So if $x$ is not algebraic, $q*x$ can not be either.

Comment: Yes.  E.g.  $\frac1{\pi}\cdot \pi=1$